# TypeORM 0.3.7 datasource connection pool suddenly closed

Tags: node.js, mariadb, typeorm

I´ve created a database controller class for my project, which creates a connection, or since 0.3.7 a datasource the following way:

```ts
            const dataSource: DataSource = new DataSource({
                type: "mariadb",
                host: process.env.DB_HOST,
                username: process.env.DB_USER,
                password: process.env.DB_PASS,
                database: database,
                logging: false,
                name: UUID.v4(),
                synchronize: false,
                entities: [path.join(__dirname, "../", "Models", "*.js")]
            });

            const createdConnection: DataSource = await dataSource.initialize();

            return Promise.resolve(new ReturnStatus(true, "Connection created", createdConnection));
```

My application requests the data the following way:

```ts
Promise.all([GetSites(), GetDetails(), GetCategories()]);
```

On the server side, each method creates a connection/datsource and the code which i showed above from my database controller gets executed.

But somehow i´m getting the following response from my server:

```
Error: Pool is closed.
    at Handshake.onConnect (C:\Users\<USER>\Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:52:15)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<USER>\ProjectAPI\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
```

The same code worked perfectly fine, before the update to version 0.3.7 and therfore i´m asking.

Do i need to do something after initializing the datasource?
Do i need to use connection instead, because in the TypeORM docs it shows, datasource.connect(), but this is marked as deprecated in my code completion.

EDIT: I can definitely confirm that this problem occurs since the changes in TypeOrm 0.3.0 and upwards